# Signing in again deletes the database in Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Database Structure in firebase]

After I login using google in firebase and store data it saves into the respective emails but when I logout and login again the data added before gets deleted.
I tried using `updatechildren` but still the data gets deleted and signing again.

`Databasemodel.kt`

```
val u_id = bdatTitleref.push().key
data class Databasemodel(val uid:String, val name:String, val dob:String,var rem:Int) {

constructor():this("",",","",0)

fun toMap():Map<String,Any>{
    return mapOf(
        "uid" to uid,
        "name" to name,
        "dob" to dob,
        "rem" to rem
    )
  }
}
```

`Mainactivity.kt`

```
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    val rootref = ref.getReference("User")
    val userref = rootref.child(uid.toString())
    val bdayTitleref = userref.child("Birthday Persons")

    val model = Databasemodel(u_id!!, et_name.text.toString().trim(), tv_show_date.text.toString(), 0)
    val postModel=model.toMap()

     bdayTitleref.child(u_id).updateChildren(postModel)
```

Here I wanted to add different child of `Birthday Persons` so help me with this

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is the use of a reference that is incorrect. When you try to update `postModel` object in your database using the following line of code:

```
bdayTitleref.child(u_id).updateChildren(postModel)
```

You are passing to the `.child(u_id)` the uid of the user (`nUmH ... TJk2`) which is not correct since in your database that child is a pushed id and not the uid of the user that comes from the authentication process.

Please note that when you create a new instance of your `Databasemodel` class and you are converting it to a `Map`, when trying to write this `Map` into a database, you tell Firebase that everything under that location should be overwritten with the new data. So in the case of `postModel`, it replaces the old value with the new one.

If you want to update the child that exists within your `Birthday Persons` node, you should consider replacing the `u_id` with `-LsjBQxNuNMZ_VBj4Hyp`:

```
bdayTitleref.child("-LsjBQxNuNMZ_VBj4Hyp").updateChildren(postModel)
```

Comment: Yes I am not using the uid that came from authentication. `val u_id = bdatTitleref.push().key` I used this way to create new u_id

Comment: In that case, you pushing a new id each time you use those lines. You should pass the existing pushed I'd and not a new one, right?

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that you only call `val u_id = bdatTitleref.push().key` once.

It'll be simpler if you just call `push()` when you're adding the new data to the database. So something like:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val rootref = ref.getReference("User")
val userref = rootref.child(uid.toString())
val bdayTitleref = userref.child("Birthday Persons")

val model = Databasemodel(u_id!!, et_name.text.toString().trim(), tv_show_date.text.toString(), 0)
val postModel=model.toMap()

bdayTitleref.push().setValue(postModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did an silly mistake when I signed in immediately added the user's uid to database so when I signed in again after logging out then it again created new node with the same uid so the previous data was deleted.